# Dependency is not satisfiable error

Tags: dependencies

I am a new user to Ubuntu and seeking for help on installing a [mod for Nautilus](https://launchpad.net/nautiluspatchtogglelocationbar/trunk/nautiluspatchtogglelocationbar/). I am running 12.04 on 32 bit machine. I do not know hot to compile all these files or what I am doing wrong. I downloaded the top file and got the following message when opening the file :

> dependency is not satisfiable

ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to install it on 12.04, with the same result. The file you mention is a .deb installer file that you can (normally) install by just double clicking. You did everything right, but it turns out that the patch cannot be installed on the latest (update of) nautilus. see [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautiluspatchtogglelocationbar/+bug/1098469).

A quick search for a possible workaround gave me this: if you have synaptic package manager installed: search for `nautilus`, select nautilus, and choose `package` from the menu, in the dropdown menu  > package > force version. then choose the previous version of nautilus:

[image]

See also [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) link to hold packages of a certain version (especially the "Introduction to Holding Packages" - section)

Comment: ok thanks for the info! there is no workaround, like maybe installing older Nautilus first?

Comment: I did a quick search, update my answer

Comment: thanks. Seems wayyyyy to complicated to just add an UP button and HOME button. Appreciate it though!

Comment: seems like I cant get 1:3.4.2 Obuntu8 which i think the package is for

Comment: you should be able to easily return to 1:3.4.1 see my updated answer with a screenshot of a fully updated 12.04) :)